# Converting 1D array to 2D array without duplicates

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

I am attempting to convert a 1D array into a 2D array([5][5]) without it using duplicate characters. I can't seem to get it to be consistent, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

Input: billys

Output: [[b, i, l, y,  ], [ ,  ,  ,  ,  ], [ ,  ,  ,  ,  ], [ ,  ,  ,  ,  ], [ ,  ,  ,  ,  ]]

Obviously missing the 's' but has correctly removed one of the 'l's

Input: billysb

output: [[b, i, l, y, s], [ ,  ,  ,  ,  ], [ ,  ,  ,  ,  ], [ ,  ,  ,  ,  ], [ ,  ,  ,  ,  ]]

Again, correctly removed the duplicate letters.

Input: billysabc

output: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9

Input: bbbbbbb

Ouput: [[b, b, b,  ,  ], [ ,  ,  ,  ,  ], [ ,  ,  ,  ,  ], [ ,  ,  ,  ,  ], [ ,  ,  ,  ,  ]]

Removing some, but not all duplicates.

here's the code doing the conversion for me:

```js
char[][] playFairGrid = new char[5][5];

//write keyword to array
        char[] keywordBreakdown = keyword.toCharArray();

        //write keyword to grid
        for(int i =0; i<5;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                if (count==keywordBreakdown.length-1) break;
                //check for duplicates
                for(int m =0; m<5;m++){
                    for(int l=0;l<5;l++){
                        if (keywordBreakdown[count]==playFairGrid[m][l]){
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                playFairGrid[i][j]=keywordBreakdown[count];
                count++;

            }
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(playFairGrid));
```

all help greatly appreciated! this has been a pain for a few hours now.

Comment: You can easily remove duplicates by adding all of the characters to a `Set<Character>`

Comment: @ClarkKent please extrapolate

Comment: "The java.util.Set interface is a subtype of the java.util.Collection interface. It represents set of objects, meaning each element can only exists once in a Set" http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/set.html

Comment: https://ideone.com/Mx4QUb

Comment: @ClarkKent You really are my superman!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create collection without duplicates you should use [Set Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)